# When should I run cleanup in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, database-administration, nodetool

Cassandra `nodetool` has a command called `cleanup`:

> cleanup [keyspace][cf_name]
>
> Triggers the immediate cleanup of keys no longer belonging to this
>   node. This has roughly the same effect on a node that a major
>   compaction does in terms of a temporary increase in disk space usage
>   and an increase in disk I/O. Optionally takes a list of column family
>   names.

My questions are:

1. When will a node having keys not belonging to it?
2. When should I issue a cleanup?
3. Should I do cleanup regularly (e.g. once per week)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When will a node having keys not belonging to it?

When you have added new nodes to the cluster, decreased replication factor or moved tokens.

> When should I issue a cleanup?

After one of the above operations, if you need to save disk space.  There is no harm in delaying running it - there is a performance impact and the only reason to is to save disk space.

> Should I do cleanup regularly (e.g. once per week)?

No, only if you need to save space after one of the above operations.

Comment: So simply delete rows or columns won't make a node having keys not belonging to it, is that right?

Comment: Correct. Deleted items are removed (once the tombstones have expired) through normal compaction, not through nodetool cleanup.

Comment: great answer. but how do I know the cleanup is finished?

Answer (score 0):

> When will a node having keys not belonging to it?

When you bootstrap a new node, some of the existing nodes will lose ownership of data by transferring the ownership to the new node.

Reducing replication factor also does this.

> When should I issue a cleanup?

After operations mentioned below, but before you start any other topology / replication change.

You should run it on all affected nodes in the cluster. When in doubt, run on all nodes.

One reason to run it is to reclaim the disk space used to store no longer owned data.

Another reason is that failure to do so may cause data consistency problems. You may see resurrection of deleted data. Consider the case of node A losing ownership of key `k` after bootstrapping a new node, and holding a live row for key `k`. Later, key k is deleted but deletion does not propagate to node A (no longer a replica). Then the deletion expires in the whole cluster. Then you change the topology such that A is the owner of key `k` again. It will serve the old, deleted, row.

Source: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/tools/nodetool/toolsCleanup.html

No need to run `nodetool cleanup` after `nodetoool decommission`, `nodetool replace`, or `nodetool removenode`.

> Should I do cleanup regularly (e.g. once per week)?

No need to.